# Get the outer neighbour pixels of contour C#

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, pixel

I have the pixel coordinates of the contour of an object. I need to get the outer neigbours of these pixels. First i calculated the middle x value and middle y value of these contour points. For every contour point I determined if the x value is higher/lower than the middle x value, I did the same for the y values. For example if the x-value of a contour point is lower than the x middle and the y value of a contour point is lower than the y middle I create a new point that is south-west to the original point. When I do this I will get 4 holes, see picture in the link below. Can someone please help me solve this problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY3uD.jpg

Comment: try great/less than or equal to instead of great/less

Comment: I already tried that